# Storing array of tuples in Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm fairly new to Laravel and very interested in their eloquent models. I'm working on a small practice project and need advice on how to best store some data.

I want to store a puppies weight and the date the weight was measured in a table (preferably in either tuples or json format). I want to later use this data to create charts using Vue in order to create charts and graphs that depict growth over time. What would be the best way to do this?

I image in the model migration there would be some sort of `$table->integer('weight'), $table->timestamp('weight-measurement-date')` or possibly `$table->json('weight-data')`, but I'm still new and unfamiliar with the best practices. Of course the database table needs to store the data without ever overwriting or erasing the previous entries. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a simple `one-to-many` relationship, so you would have a `puppies` table and a `measurements` table, where the `measurements` table holds all the different measurements that took place.

[image: erd]

This will allow you to add as many measurements as you want for a specific puppy.

I chose `measured_at` instead of `weighed_at` for the date that the puppy was weighed at because maybe down the line you add a new column to the measurements table (height for example), so I think it would make sense to use `measured_at` instead of `weighed_at` since you probably don't want multiple dates for the measurements.

To get started you can use the following:

```
php artisan make:migration create_puppies_table

php artisan make:migration create_measurements_table
```

and then add the following to your migrations.

puppies migration:

```
Schema::create('puppies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

measurements migration:

```
Schema::create('measurements', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('puppy_id')->constrained();
    $table->timestamp('measured_at');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

You then would need two models `Puppy` and `Measurement` where you can define your relationship methods:

Puppy model:

```
public function measurements()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Measurement');
}
```

Measurement model:

```
public function puppy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Puppy');
}
```

You can read more about eloquent and relationships in the docs:

[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent)

[One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

PS:

The only thing you would have to think about is how you want to store the weight, maybe a `decimal` or maybe an `integer`, if you store it as an integer you would have to convert it each time you retrieve / store it in the database.